# Could not find any version that matches com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:+

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-gradle-plugin, cordova-plugins

I have to used [Android-Image-Cropper](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper) in my custom cordoava plugin, for that added gardle file to maintain dependency.

```
        //build.gradle

        dependencies {
            repositories {
                  mavenCentral()
            }
            compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
            compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.3.1'
            compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:+'
        }
```

but at the time of build project(Application developed in Ionic) I got the following error

```
        FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

        * What went wrong:

        A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
        > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
           > Could not find any version that matches com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:+.
             Searched in the following locations:
                 https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/theartofdev/edmodo/android-image-cropper/maven-metadata.xml

                 https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/theartofdev/edmodo/android-image-cropper/
                 file:/Users/santosh/Documents/Developer/android-sdk-macosx/extras/android/m2repository/com/theartofdev/edmodo/android-image-cropper/maven-metadata.xml
                 file:/Users/santosh/Documents/Developer/android-sdk-macosx/extras/android/m2repository/com/theartofdev/edmodo/android-image-cropper/
                 file:/Users/santosh/Documents/Developer/android-sdk-macosx/extras/google/m2repository/com/theartofdev/edmodo/android-image-cropper/maven-metadata.xml
                 file:/Users/santosh/Documents/Developer/android-sdk-macosx/extras/google/m2repository/com/theartofdev/edmodo/android-image-cropper/
             Required by:
                 :android:unspecified
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Add JCenter](https://bintray.com/arthurhub/maven/Android-Image-Cropper/) to your repositories

```
repositories {
    jcenter() 
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.3.1'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.+'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.1.4'
```

This works fine for me.

Comment: Thank you and sorry it not works got the error now Could not find com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.1.4.